# Can i use HDMI audio only without video?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, 16.10, xrandr

I am using `ubuntu 16.10` and sometimes i just need better speakers .
At the office i have a huge lcd display which is too bright for such close distance but i still would like to use it as audio device.
Is this possible without sending video just to use audio ?